# Spring Boot Cacheable - Cache null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I am using `@Cacheable` annotation to cache the results of my method. For performance reason I want to cache both `null` and non-null values returned from method.

But problem here is Spring is caching non-null values but not caching null for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
@Cacheable(
            cacheManager = "promoCacheManager",
            value = "promos:campaign",
            key = "'promos:campaign:'.concat(#currencyId)"
    )
    public PromosDto getPromosByCurrency(Integer currencyId) {

...
```

I have tried every thing. Even I set

`unless = "#result != null || #result == null"`

But that didn't help as well.
Any pointer on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your cache manager settings.

**For example:** `RedisCacheManager` has an overloaded constructor where you can specify `cacheNullValues`; this is false by default - try setting it to true.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.html#RedisCacheManager-org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations-java.util.Collection-boolean-

Also keep in mind:

> NOTE When enabling cacheNullValues please make sure the RedisSerializer used by RedisOperations is capable of serializing NullValue.

Answer (score 3):

Why not return `Optional<PromosDto>` to safely wrap a null. That should cache fine then, according to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition

Comment: Not working for me. Still same. It cache only if object inside optional is not-null.

Comment: Does your cache provider support caching nulls?

Comment: yes, I am using Redis Cache. So it does support null values